# Unit testing a Firemonkey Application

Tags: delphi, unit-testing, n-tier-architecture, firemonkey, dunit

I'm trying to use DUnit, which came with RAD Studio XE2, to unit testing a Firemonkey app (C++).

The problem is, DUnit is a VCL project, and this makes me unable to include the Firemonkey Unit Forms (ex.: UfrmMain.h) on the testing project.

Even if I separate the Visual with Logic (MultiTier/MVC), i cannot include any Firemonkey library into my classes (sometimes this would be useful, when there is a class "CustomDatabase" which have a object of type TConnection, that is only available in Firemonkey - **of course** only an example).

The testing is possible when i separate the firemonkey code completely and leave it on forms, and the logic/data kept on classes with pure C++ code.

So, this "handicap" is actually a good thing? Forcing me to work with MultiTier/MVC? (This thing in C++ is new to me)
Or should i look for an alternative of unit testing, that lets me test forms too?

(Can you also recommend me some C++ project on github or code example which is separated in the mentioned way, where i can rely on?)

Comment: Sounds like it's time for some enterprising Delphi haxxor to write a DUnitFMX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible approach would be to use `TextTestRunner` rather than `GUITestRunner`. I've never actually tried this but I think it quite plausible that `TextTestRunner` does not use any VCL units, or at the very least what it does use can easily be excised. And indeed a quick scan of the source code suggests that this will work.

Comment: kind of works. (i had to change the "FrameworkType" from VCL to FMX on ".cbproj" of test project to compile, but now the project requires a .obj file from an 3rdparty component file. almost giving up of firemonkey =/